# Convert some database data (SQL Table) to .csv format

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I want to convert some database data to .csv format. 
At the beginning, I create a connection with a database then create a cursor instance, send query through that cursor instance, fetch your data & close the connection. 
My problem is that I can't visualize the headers of the table, I get just the content.

```
import pyodbc
import csv

connection = pyodbc.connect("Driver={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server};"
                  "Server=*****;"
                  "Database=****;"
                  "uid=****;pwd=****")

 cursor = connection.cursor()
 cursor.execute("Select * from Table")
 data=cursor.fetchall()

 with open('test.csv', 'w', newline= '') as f:
a = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
a.writerows(data)  
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use pandas for reading data from db to export into csv

```
import pandas as pd
sql='Select * from Table'
df= pd.read_sql(sql,sql_connection)
df.to_csv('csv_filename')
```